# Regex for password without special characters

Tags: regex

I have a requirement to validate password using a regex

- Password should contain at least four characters,

  - at least one lower case character,
  - at least one upper case character,
  - at least one number

`^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{4,}$`

I have above regex working but it accepts any special character. How can i reject it , Please guide

Comment: replace the `.` outside of the lookaheads by a character class matching the characters you wish to accept, e.g. `[0-9a-zA-Z]` (you can replace the `.` inside the lookaheads too although it's not necessary, I'd check whether it increases performances in cases with and without special characters)

Comment: Aside: It's usually a bad idea to enforce these kind of password restrictions.

Comment: Which programming language or other framework are you using? As the answer of @James McGuigan suggests, it will be easier to combine several regexes using code. PS: I find it really annoying when I need to change the settings of my password manager to accomodate for such special requirements. Yours are still acceptable in comparison to some other requirements though :D

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be easier and cleaner to validate each rule separately

```
def validate_password(password: str) -> bool: 
  return bool(
        len(password) >= 4 and 
    and re.search(r'[a-z]', password) 
    and re.search(r'[A-Z]', password)
    and re.search(r'[0-9]', password)
    and not re.search(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', password)  # exclude non alphanumeric
  )
```

Else you could use a negative lookahead assertion

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).{4,}$
```

Comment: Wow I didn't know there's types in Python! Why is nobody else using them? o_O

Comment: Technically they are only "type hints", which is a form of extended documentation that can be used by IDEs, linters, type checkers and autocomplete. Unlike Java/Scala they are not actually enforced by the runtime.

The new inline syntax was added in Python3, but the same effect can be achieved in Python2 by using type comments.

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html
- https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python2.html

Comment: Type checking at runtime can done using `isinstance()`, which can check for primitives (int, float, str, bool, list, tuple, dict) and classes

- https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_isinstance.asp